# How to build appx file for windows store in xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, windows-store-apps

I was searching in the internet but I don't found anything. How can I create release appx file in visual studio using xamarin?
Thanks!

Comment: Like usual wp project, **right button on project** -> **Store** -> **Create App Packages**

Comment: Yes! :D But it's important to select in solution explorer windows phone project not any other. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right button on `Windows` or `Windows phone` project -> Store -> Create App Packages

[image]

Comment: please add adnotation that in solution explorer windows phone project must be selected windows phone project :)

Comment: Edited, please, check)